# I Opened an iPad app second view, now need to return to the first view

Tags: ios, ipad

I am working on an iPad app with two views.  The first view is defined in MainWindow.xib.  The sccond view is defined in View2.xib.  A button in MainWindow.xib initiates the code below and activates View2.  It works great.  Now I need to return to the MainWindow.xib view.  I tried the same code (but in reverse) and it did not work.  I got a SIGABT error in main.  I would appreciate some suggestions as to how to efficiently return from View2 to MainWindow.

Following is the code mentioned above.

```
if(!View2Controller)
{
View2Controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nill];
}
[self presentModalViewController:View2Controller animated:YES];

if(view2Controller.view.superview)
{
[view2Controller.view removeFromSuperView];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
 [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using that in your `View2`:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks to all for comments. I tried both of the snippets described, and neither is working.  The error, in main, is "Thread1: Program received signal SIGABT"

Comment: @K17 try deleting this line of code: `[view2Controller.view removeFromSuperView];`

Comment: If I do that, we never see View2.  would need another way to show View2.

Answer (score 0):

In your `View2Controller` `.m` file, in the event where you want to go back to the main view (for ex. a button click), implement the following code:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use protocol implementation.